# Change the URL for Github pages set to Private

Tags: github-pages, custom-domain

I have a number of repos that use a custom domain to give the Github pages consistent URLs (all set to Public). I would like to make the Github pages private, but then they are published to some Github assigned URL. Can you change the URL on private Github pages to match your custom domain? If so, how?

Answer (score -1):

To be able to have a custom domain on a private repo, you would need either GitHub Pro, GitHub Team, GitHub Enterprise Cloud, or GitHub Enterprise Server. Custom domains are not available for private repos on a free account.

https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site